# "...glue these shapes to the side of the box that doesn't have the drawers on." Why is there ".....on" at the end?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

This is from a native British speaker[Mr. maker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRiq4hLIB90) see 0:50-0:55

**"...and carefully cut them out then glue these shapes to the side of the box that doesn't have the drawers on."**

I don't understand why there is an **"on"** at the end.

The box is a box which is composed of the stacking match boxes and gluing  them together, So, one side of the box has drawers and the other side does not have the drawers.

So, **"......side of the box that does not have drawers"** would be fine.

Why **"....on"** at the end?

Comment: The British often do this: they say: "the side of the box that doesn't have drawers on" to mean "the side of the box that doesn't have drawers on it". aka with no drawers.

Comment: I would have said "...that doesn't have the drawers _in it_", since the drawers are part of the structure and not just a surface feature. But people don't always use prepositions logically.

Answer (score 0):

He said, "*the **side** that doesn't have the drawers on*".

It's common to say that something is 'on' a side. Looking at the box he had made, the opening for the drawers was on one side, and the reverse was just a plain side. If he had been talking about the opposite side, he might well have said "*on the side with the drawers*".

It isn't unusual to move a preposition like 'on' to the end of a sentence, for example:

- He took off his shoes
- He took his shoes off
- He put on his hat
- He put his hat on
- You're only supposed to blow the bloody doors off
- You're only supposed to blow off the bloody doors

Comment: Thanks for the answer. He said "the side of the box that doesn't have the drawers on". Secondly I know that saying "something is on a side" is common, but this does not seem to be that structure. If it had been that structure, then the sentence would have been ""the side of the box which the drawers are on.". They would not have needed the verb "have", would they?

Comment: @Yunus look at the examples I included. You can place the preposition differently, perhaps that is why you don't think it is an idiomatic construction. But take it from a native English speaker, it's perfectly common.

Comment: I looked at the examples, they are all phrasal verbs. "take on", "take off" etc. and I understand the prepositions can be put at the end. But what is the phrasal verb in the sentence in question? There is no phrasal verb, is there?

Comment: @yunus the verb is "glue". We use this as a verb to mean 'stick' or 'attach' when using glue.